# Getting Apple Mach-O Linker Error trying when trying to build archive

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I got [this error](http://pastebin.com/mQQazZ2X) when trying to Archive for distribution.

My app builds fine when running on my phone or the simulator.

I've narrowed it down to the Build Locations under my Kal libraries Build Settings. The pre-configuration Build Product Paths only has my two original configurations: Debug and Release. However, my RestKit library automatically added my Distribution configuration.

Could that be why it is not archiving? It does not have my configuration? How do I add my configuration to the library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a configuration with the same name in the library (duplicate from Release).

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was solved by:

1. installing the Xcode command line tools
   (Xcode Preferences -> Downloads -> Components -> Command Line Tools -> Install)
2. Recreating the Phonegap project